# How would be the most efficient method to manage page themes on a MVC framework?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, themes, customization

I'm trying build a MVC framework, but I'm confused about manage themes. Well... I want a way to manage themes but that allows customize pages. The page can follow theme skeleton, but in some cases, it could be follow self theme (custom theme) or customize any part of theme (customize specific part of theme). Any ideas to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes have nothing to do with MVC or with frameworks. Framework is a tool for programming, not for content and design management.

Closes intersection of both would be when it comes to templates, which are used by instances of view class. If you want to learn how to utilize native PHP for templating, you should read [**this article**](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html).

Other then that, themes are front-end matter. To change applications theme, one has to change CSS, graphics( images, some decorative flash animations) and/or JavaScript files. If you need to change the HTML you're working with, then you need to also ability to change templates.

So, in conclusion, if you want for MVC framework to facilitate theme-able applications, you have must have some sort of option, which contains `template directory`. Preferably at bootstrap stage. Then anyone who uses that framework can easily expand bootstrap, to dynamically read the location of of current path to templates. And templates themselves contain paths to all the other details for the theme (css, images, js).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to determine what level of access to the design your user is going to have.  For example, if your views are completely accessible to the user, then your "theme" is done; it's the view.  This is the point of having MVC, no?  You are creating this framework to separate for coders, designers, and db managers right?

Comment: Do you mean that I have to do distinct "views themes" for each page?

Comment: You would probably want to build your theme options into your controller, right?  Perhaps you could clarify more of what you're trying to do.  Are you building a MVC framework or are you using a pre-existing MVC framework?

Comment: The first option :) I will clarify: I want the pages follow a predefined layout, but, in some cases, the page could be personalized. An example: the facebook user profile pages follows a specific layout. But the "about pages" (http://www.facebook.com/about/pages) is a page with informations about company pages and it is a personalized page of site.

Comment: The simple way to do this would be to insert a PHP object in the view code itself, and test against it at runtime. I'm assuming you are building in PHP. That seems oversimplified but that is how you would do it in CakePHP etc.

Comment: Thank very much for help! I'm using Smarty template engine :)

Comment: Smarty is good, dirty (that's good), and fun.  Easier to learn than CakePHP, and more documented, obviously.  So you are building not a framework but using Smarty as a framework.  Post one of your views in HTML and I'll try to help with the PHP end of it.

Comment: No no! I'm not using Smarty as MVC. I'm using as template system of my MVC framework.